# Google Map Marker userData is becomes nil after Cluster iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I am using Google Maps in iOS app.
I set **userData** to markers, some String for example.

```
marker.userData = "SOME_ID"
```

When I tap on the marker I can get this **userData** without problem from any marker.

```
let data = marker.userData
```

I also use [Clastering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/marker-clustering) for my markers. When markers are grouped to cluster and when they are moved out of cluster(ungroupped), **marker.userData** becomes nil. For all markers. Why does it happen and how to prevent it ?

Comment: Did you find solution for this ? Even I am getting it as nil

Answer (score 1):

I also got this issue and after many try it didn't worked.
Finally I made subclass of `GMSMarker` and declared a custom variable, and that solved the problem for me.

Comment: This one can actually help !